# How to draw a flat plane in openGL by drawing triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, terrain

```
void Terrain::draw_terrain(const Input& in)
{

    this->P = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    this->V = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    this->M = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    P = in.P;
    V = in.V;

    M = glm::scale(M, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    // loop through each row
    for (int row = 0; row < terrain_height; row++)
    {
        int col;
        // adding a row of vertices
        for (col = 0; col < terrain_width - 1; col++) {
            // x, y, z, 1
            terrain_verts.emplace_back(col, row, 0.0f, 1);

        }

        // adding a row of indices
        // blue color
        for (col = 0; col < terrain_width - 1; col++)
        {
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + row * terrain_width);
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + row * terrain_width + 1);
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + terrain_width * (row + 1) - 1);
        }

        // green color
        for (col = terrain_width - 1; col > 0; col--)
        {
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + row * terrain_width);
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + terrain_width * (row + 1) - 1);
            terrain_indices.emplace_back(col + terrain_width * (row + 1));
        }

        // adding a row of texture coordinates
        if (row % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < terrain_width; col += 2)
            {
                terrain_texture_coordinates.emplace_back(0, 0);
                terrain_texture_coordinates.emplace_back(1, 0);
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            for (col = 0; col < terrain_width; col += 2)
            {
                terrain_texture_coordinates.emplace_back(0, 1);
                terrain_texture_coordinates.emplace_back(1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    spLambertTextured->use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(spLambertTextured->u("P"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(P));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(spLambertTextured->u("V"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(V));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("vertex"));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("texCoord"));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("normal"));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(spLambertTextured->u("M"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(M));

    glVertexAttribPointer(spLambertTextured->a("vertex"), 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, terrain_verts.data());
    glVertexAttribPointer(spLambertTextured->a("texCoord"), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, terrain_texture_coordinates.data());
    glVertexAttribPointer(spLambertTextured->a("normal"), 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, terrain_norms.data());

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUniform1i(spLambertTextured->u("tex"), 0);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, terrain_indices_count(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, terrain_indices.data());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("vertex"));
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("color"));
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(spLambertTextured->a("normal"));

}
```

First, I added all of the vertices in a first 'for' loop. Then I wanted to add indices by first going in blue direstion, then green direction. Next, I would go upwards, looping through every row. I set terrain_width and terrain_height to 6. The result is on the red background.

[image: order in which I wanted to draw indices]

[image: result I got]

How to fix the indexing in order to have a flat plane?

Comment: What plane are you talking about? Is the math correct?

Comment: I meant to draw flat surface which will be textured with grass.

Comment: Why do you need more than two triangles if it's going to be flat anyway?

Comment: I wanted to have grass mosaic, so that it looks more realistic.

Comment: I fixed it, but the texture is not showing. I debugged it and the tex has value of 3. I think that it is an indicator that it is bound.

Comment: Even with two triangles you can adjust your texture parameters to repeat. But yes if you want to start blending textures later more triangle make sense. It looked like you only defined half the triangles next to [0,1,10] there should also be a [1,10,11] (disclaimer I'm not used to opengl)

Comment: @PKramer I changed the loops ``` for (col = 0; col < terrain_width; col++) {
  

  }

  // adding a row of indices
  for (col = 0; col < terrain_width; col++)
  {
   
  }

  for (col = terrain_width - 1; col >= 0; col--)
  {
   
  }
```

Comment: I see my numbers where incorrect, but that you got the point :)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to add some value to the z-component of your vertices. Setting all z = 0.0f, essentially makes it a 2D plane, and you may not see the texture effectively.

Comment: I checked it and if I set z=0.01f or z=0.1f ,the surface moves upwards.

Comment: For texture coordinates, vert num 0, it would be a coordinate (0,0), then:
vert 1 -> (1,0)
vert 2 -> (0,0)
vert 3 -> (1,0)
vert 4 -> (0,0)
vert 5 -> (1,0)
then next now...
vert 6 -> (0,1)
vert 7 -> (1,1)
vert 8 -> (0,1)
...
is that correct or should I split it more?